# How to change wheel picker lines color and thickness? (SwiftUI)

Tags: colors, swiftui, picker

I want to change this gray lines color of the default wheel picker to white.
Is it possible or I have to implement whole picker by myself?
And may be it is possible to change the line thickness?

[image: wheel picker]

Answer (score 0):

I think you’ll need to write a custom picker by yourself. It is impossible to change or even hide the  selection indicator since iOS 7:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipickerview/1614373-showsselectionindicator?language=objc